# Run shell command in jenkins as root user?

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, root

I have recently started using Jenkins for integration. All was well until I was running jobs on master node without shell command but I have to run jobs on master as well as slave node which contains shell commands to. I am not able to run those shell commands as root user. I have tried

1. Using `SSH Keys`.
2. Setting user name in shell commands.
3. Using `sudo`.

I am getting `permission denied` error every time I use any of the above methods.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to modify the permission for `jenkins` user so that you can run the shell commands.
You can install the jenkins as as service (download the rpm package), You might need to change the ports because by default it runs http on 8080 and AJP on 8009 port.

Following process is for `CentOS`
1. Open up the this script (using VIM or other editor):

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

2. Find this `$JENKINS_USER` and change to “root”:

```
$JENKINS_USER="root"
```

3. Then change the ownership of Jenkins home, webroot and logs:

```
chown -R root:root /var/lib/jenkins
chown -R root:root /var/cache/jenkins
chown -R root:root /var/log/jenkins
```

4)  Restart Jenkins and check the user has been changed:

```
service jenkins restart
ps -ef | grep jenkins
```

### Now you should be able to run the Jenkins jobs as the root user and all the shell command will be executed as `root`.

Comment: It is a really bad idea to run services that are expose a webinterface that allow you to run scripts, as root.

Comment: +1 for @JamesP. However incorrect installation of aws cli and Jenkins user permission can cause this issue.

Comment: Any idea, how can I do this in MacOSX?

Comment: dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership jenkins

Comment: This looked promising, however later i reverted, dint use the above commands, yet to find a better solution.

Comment: In case of Ubuntu, edit this file:  /etc/default/jenkins

Comment: It doesn't work, it crashed my Jenkins to zero

Comment: totally waste solution, becoz of this solution now m unable to start my Jenkins service.

Answer (score 46):

I would suggest against running the jenkins user as root.  This could expose the operating system and all of the repo's which jenkins can build.

Running any script as root is a security risk, but a slightly safer method would be to grant the jenkins user sudo access to only run the one script, without needing a password.

```
sudo visudo
```

and add the following:

```
jenkins    ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/[job name]/workspace/script
```

Double check your path via the console log of a failed build script. The one shown here is the default.

Now within the jenkins task you can call `sudo $WORKSPACE/your script`

Comment: then I need to append `sudo` to every command in my jenkinsfile, is that really the right approach?

Comment: @JulioMarins Generally no, if you can find an alternative approach then take it. But if you need to use root access then this is the safer way to do it. Remember that if the script you are running is compromised then so is the Jenkins server.

Comment: to your second step add the file name being modified...  sudo vi /etc/sudoers

Answer (score 3):

**For Linux try to follow these steps:-**

This worked for me.

Change Jenkins user: `sudo vi /etc/default/jenkins`

Change user root or your user that you use to access to your files:
`$JENKINS_USER="root"`

Execute using the user that you setup before:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /var/lib/jenkins
sudo chown -R root:root /var/cache/jenkins
sudo chown -R root:root /var/log/jenkins
```

3. Run as a services:

   `service jenkins restart`
   Or
   `systemctl jenkins restart`

You can execute jenkins has a process and disable headless mode for Linux with UI.

```
/etc/alternatives/java -Djava.awt.headless=false -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
```

Validate Jenkins is running currently:
`ps -ef | grep jenkins`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set up a jenkins "Slave" that is actually running as root on the master and restrict it to tied jobs, then point your job at that slave. Far from ideal but certainly a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change the permission of `docker.sock`. Make sure your docker container is running the user as `root`

```
docker exec <jenkinsContainerID> chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with all  the steps mentioned in the **selected answer**, I had to do the following:

1. Identify where the Jenkins service file is, on Centos 7/8

   `vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service`
2. Specify the `root` user instead of `jenkins` user

   `User=root`

   `Group=root`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with the EC2 "Azazon Linux 2023 AMI". I have checked many solutions but unfortunately, nothing works as one step is missing to **Overring service configurations**.

> `vi user/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service`. Here in the file need
> to change the `User=root`, and `Group=root` as by default it will be `jenkins`
> . Run this `systemctl daemon-reload`

then

> vi /etc/sysconfig/jenkins change the `JENKINS_USER="root"`
>
> chown -R root:root /var/lib/jenkins
>
> chown -R root:root /var/cache/jenkins
>
> chown -R root:root /var/log/jenkins

After this work like the charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but was not allowed to execute `sudo visudo`. Instead I created `/etc/sudoers.d/jenkins` file and put this line in it

```
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD:/var/lib/jenkins/scripts/script.sh
```

Comment: P.S. If someone have any doubts about possible security issues with this approach, please let me know

Answer (score -2):

You just need to run the shell command on Linux machine using Root privileges from Jenkins.

Steps :

1) `sudo vi /etc/sudoers`

2) Add line :

```
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD:/path of script/
```

3) From Jenkins,run the script on remote shell using sudo .
for eg : `sudo ps -ef`

4) Build Jenkins job now.
This job runs the script on Linux machine using root privileges.