# Jenkins : npm install fail without sudo

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I need to execute **npm install** command without **sudo** but i got this error in my Jenkins job when i tried to execute this command
this is the error console message:

```
+ npm install
```

> npm WARN grunt-bump@0.8.0 requires a peer of grunt@>=1.0.1 but none
>   was installed. npm WARN Site_mmm@0.0.1 No repository field. npm WARN
>   Site_mmm@0.0.1 No license field. npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-32-generic npm
>   ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" npm
>   ERR! node v5.1.0 npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2 npm ERR! path
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mmm/node_modules/.staging npm ERR! code
>   EACCES npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! syscall mkdir
>
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
>   '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Site_SiFAST_-_Intégration_Continue/node_modules/.staging'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native) npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission
>   denied, mkdir
>   '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Site_SiFAST_-_Intégration_Continue/node_modules/.staging']
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall:
>   'mkdir', npm ERR!   path:
>   '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Site_SiFAST_-_Intégration_Continue/node_modules/.staging'
>   } npm ERR!  npm ERR! Please try running this command again as
>   root/Administrator.

Anyone khow how to execute this command without sudo?

Comment: Have you seen this https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change to access of the directory for which you are getting error by using chmod command .change it in such a way that Jenkins user is able to create directory

Answer (score 0):

thanks @pushpendra chouchan :
Fixed by :

```
sudo chown -R [jenkins-user] /user/local/lib/node_modules/
sudo chown -R [jenkins-user] /user/local/bin/
sudo chown -R [jenkins-user] /user/local/lib/share/
```

Comment: a spelling mistake: user should be usr

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to find here:
[Run shell command in jenkins as root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926773/run-shell-command-in-jenkins-as-root-user)

jenkins user is per default not a sudoer(https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo#Using_visudo).
So its not possible to add sudo before a command.

you can try to add jenkins to sudoers but this wasnt working for me.
i did it that way from the link i added.

make changes in jenkins config file /etc/default/jenkins (for most of the linux distributions) or /etc/sysconfig/jenkins (for redhat/centOS distribution)