# Pybot not seen by "which" command in Jenkins shell execution

Tags: jenkins, debian, robotframework

Started by user anonymous

```
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Run script
[Run script] $ /bin/bash -xe /tmp/jenkins2969604061590363450.sh
+ which java
/usr/bin/java
+ which pybot
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The problem is that Jenkins can't recognize the path for pybot, where the very same commands works fine in command line:

```
user@test-vm:/home$ which pybot
/opt/test-vm/python/bin/pybot
```

Where is the problem? Should I add it to the PATH somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `user` is the same user that is used during build? Maybe there is line in `.profile` or `.bashrc` that modifies the `PATH` for the `user`?

Comment: No, seems that jenkins runs it as anonymous user (whatever it is).

Comment: Than modify `PATH` variable for that user or simply put line that modifies `PATH` in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I had to change Jenkins user - this question's anwers are helpful:

[Run shell command in jenkins as root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926773/run-shell-command-in-jenkins-as-root-user)