# Maven directory : Permission denied

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins

I have installed Maven and Jenkins in my linux server. Maven is executing perfectly fine from putty. But from Jenkins when I am trying to run the pipeline job with maven I am getting the following error: /data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5/bin/mvn : Permission denied

The pipeline code is as below:

> ```
> node {
>    def mvnHome
>    stage('Preparation') { 
>       git branch: 'master', url: "http://UN:PW@IP/root/Test-Repo.git", credentialsId: 'QPGitCred'      
>       mvnHome = tool 'org.apache.maven_3.2.5'
>    }
>    stage('Build') {
>       if (isUnix()) {
>          sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' --version"
>       } else {
>          bat(/"${mvnHome}\bin\mvn" --version/)
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

Console Output:

```
    Started by user jenkins_dev Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline [Pipeline] node Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PipelineJob1 [Pipeline] { [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Preparation) [Pipeline] git using credential QPGitCred
     git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
     git config remote.origin.url http://UN:PW@IP/root/Test-Repo.git # timeout=10 Fetching upstream changes from http://UN@IP/root/Test-Repo.git
     git --version # timeout=10 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials QPGitCred
     git fetch --tags --progress http://UN@IP/root/Test-Repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
     git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
     git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10 Checking out Revision 0051ce3ezza8457e44e890c1cad8z2c93de19bd0 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
     git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
     git checkout -f 0051ce3rrda8457e44e890c1cad8f2z93de19bd0
     git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
     git branch -D master # timeout=10
     git checkout -b master 0051ce3ebda8457e44e890c1cad8f2c49de19bd0 Commit message: "Update pom.xml"
     git rev-list --no-walk 0051ce3ebda8121e44h890c1cuy8f2c93de19bd0 # timeout=10 [Pipeline] tool [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Build) [Pipeline] isUnix [Pipeline] sh
    + /data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5/bin/mvn
    --version /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PipelineJob1@tmp/durable-990d0f84/script.sh: line 1: 
/data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5/bin/mvn: Permission denied [Pipeline] } 
[Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] 
// node [Pipeline] End of 
Pipeline ERROR: script returned exit code 1 Finished: FAILURE
```

From putty I checked permission with below command :

```
ls -l /data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5/bin/mvn

-rwxrwxrwx 1 testusr dba 5543 Dec 14  2014 /data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5/bin/mvn
```

Here permission shows it has right to execute this file. But still from Jenkins I am getting Permission denied error.

Thanks for your response in advance.

Comment: What operating system? Is SELinux installed and in enforcing mode?

Answer (score 0):

Add bash command to print current user/group and file right of `mvn` as following. 
Such info can help to confirm the user/group and file right are as expect.

```
stage('Build') {
  if (isUnix()) {
     sh """
       # print current user, group
       id

       # print folder's user group/access
       ls -l "${mvnHome}"/..
       ls -l "${mvnHome}"

       "${mvnHome}"/bin/mvn --version
     """
  } else {
     bat(/"${mvnHome}\bin\mvn" --version/)
  }
}
```

Comment: I included the bash command and I got the following output in Jenkins:                + id
uid=773(jenkins) gid=986(jenkins) groups=986(jenkins)
+ ls -l /data1/SOA_INFRA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5/bin/mvn
ls: cannot access /data1/SOA/app/oracle/product/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5/bin/mvn: Permission denied

Comment: I did some changes to print the `bin` parent folder's user group. Possible the current user `jenkins` is not the owner of `bin` parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your response.

I was able to resolve this issue by configuring Jenkins as root user. I followed the steps given in this link: [Run shell command in jenkins as root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926773/run-shell-command-in-jenkins-as-root-user)

Following process is for CentOS:

1. Open up the this script (using VIM or other editor):

   vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
2. Find this $JENKINS_USER and change to “root”:

   $JENKINS_USER="root"
3. Then change the ownership of Jenkins home, webroot and logs:

   chown -R root:root /var/lib/jenkins
   chown -R root:root /var/cache/jenkins
   chown -R root:root /var/log/jenkins