# Jenkins : Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: jenkins, passwords

I'm trying to copy files using scp command from jenkins (ci/cd). But i got permission denied error. If i'm trying manually from diffrent servers, its all done, at the same time i tried the same command in jenkins exes command, then i got error.

Configure > Build > execute shell

and the console output is like below,

> [nginx_server] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins7685256768444698.sh
>
> - scp 111 ubuntu@34.229.202.9:/home/ubuntu Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied, please try again. ubuntu@34.229.202.9:
>   Permission denied (publickey,password). lost connection Build step
>   'Execute shell' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

if anyone know the solution, please answer...

Comment: Jenkins normally runs under a different account than you're logged in. Change that account or give the Jenkins account write-permission on the destination. This might help [Run as root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926773/run-shell-command-in-jenkins-as-root-user) - don't run it as root but you can change the user it's run on

Answer (score 0):

Add your ssh key as a secret to Jenkins.

In your pipeline use **sshagent**:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Stage_name') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sshagent (credentials: ['secret_name']) {
                        sh "scp ... "
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```